# Pass variable between procs in the same namespace

Tags: variables, namespaces, tcl, proc

I have two procs in the same namespace

```
proc myNamespace::function {} {
  set myVar "Hello"
}

proc myNamespace::otherFunction {} {
  global myVar
  puts $myVar
}
```

Now for some reason this does not work. I have tried using `upvar #0` to make `myVar` a global variable. I have tried doing `global myNamespace::myVar` in `otherFunction`, nothing seems to work. I just want to be able to have `myVar` be a variable in the `myNamespace` namespace. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
proc myNamespace::function {} {
    variable myVar
    set myVar "Hello"
}

proc myNamespace::otherFunction {} {
    variable myVar
    puts $myVar
}
```

Variables created within a command are always local variables unless they are expressly declared to be namespace variables (with the `variable` command) or global variables (with the `global` command). Tcl doesn't use lexical scoping, so a command never just picks up variables from the surrounding scope. It is also possible to use namespace or global variables without declarations if one uses namespace-qualified names such as `::foo::bar` (the namespace variable `bar` in the `foo` namespace which is a child of the `::` namespace) or `::baz` (the global variable `baz`).

Documentation: [global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [variable](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/variable.htm)